# SQL database programming for applications general question

Tags: sql

This is just a general question about what to do with CRUD operations on a web server. Every time the user (for example) wants to post in a certain group, should we always check to see if that group exists before performing the `INSERT` operation, by doing something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM groups 
WHERE id = 'group_id';
```

or is that not preferred because it would cause performance issues? But it is also safer...

Comment: It is safer, but not 100% foolproof. In a multi-user multi-threaded environment it can always happen that the group is removed between the check you perform and the subsequent insertion. It's easier to rely on database constraints, like a foreign key.

Comment: I think it's better to add some `UNIQUE` constraints and let the integrity check do the job for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused about your design where a user could specify a group that doesn't exist.  That seems to be the root cause of the issue.

To prevent "posting to a group that doesn't exist", you would define a foreign key from the `groupId` in `posts` to the `groups` table.  Voila.  The database ensures that they exist.

But further . . . having the `groupId` implies that the group exists.  So, if your code is using ids "under the hood", then this is not an issue at all.

Comment: I think something that could happen is if the user navigates to a screen to post to a group, and once they navigation, the app fetches all of the groups. But between the fetch and the time when the user posts, a group could be deleted

Comment: @MichaelHsu . . . If that is a concern (the deletion of groups), then a foreign key relationship should suffice.  An attempt to insert a post using a deleted group would result in an error.